# How to look up if a whole column contains any of the words in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I am trying to check if a column in sheet1 matches a column in sheet2, which are not in the same row order.

They are Names of customers that might not match exactly one another, however it still can be the same customer...

How can I run a formula/code to do this check?

I tried using

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LEFT(sfdc!C:C, 50),B2)), "OK", "NOT OK")
```

to check the first 50 letters of the cell, but no success...

Comment: I think you could use `COUNTIFS()` with a wildcard?

Comment: Why don't you share a few cases (better all) that could occur e.g. `Ana Laura Bianco` vs `Ana Bianco` vs `A. L. Bianco` vs `Bianco Ana` vs etc.?

Comment: That would be examples indeed! FOr example, the name on one sheet might be Ana Bianco, but showing Ana Laura Bianco on the other @VBasic2008

Answer (score 1):

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(E2,$B$2:$B$16,0),"no match")
```

This checks one by one the lines of the new table vs the old table (frozen columns and rows $ so that you can drag the formula to the whole column)
The match function is wrapped with a IFERROR to handle non existing matches.

[image: Screenshot of the end result]

Comment: But the name might not be exactly the same...

Comment: if it is not exactly the same then we should think what cases we would cover

e.g. is it <name surname> to <surname name> (split and reverse join), is it partial match that <name surname> is part of the <name surname extra text2> (search first in the second)?